# select all the subchilds details in jpa self refence for dynamic hierarchy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, playframework

I am using play 2.3.x with java jpa mysql and got stuck in database problem.I have entity `Executive` which I am self refrencing with relation of `One-to-Many`(I am using this because I want to create a dynamic hierarchical database).

**Executive.java** model

```
@Entity
public class Executive {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String full_name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Executive upperExecutive;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="upperExecutive")
    private Collection<Executive> lowerExecutives;

    private String type;

}
```

so given an id of executive I want to find all the subuser of it so I did a simple select like

```
public static Executive getHierachyUser(Long id) {

    Executive executive = (Executive)JPA.em().createQuery("select e from Executive e where e.id=:id").setParameter("id",id).getSingleResult();

    return executive;
}
```

But in the view I dont know how long the hierarchy is so I dont know how to get all the executive of below certain executive.So if my hierarchy is

[image: hierarchy]

In my view I am passing the found executive object and doing `getlowerExecutive()` but  how do I know I have to continue it after user4 and stop doing it after user6.what I am doing now

```
 <ol>
        @for(executive <- executiveList) {
           <li>@executive.getFull_name

               @if(executive.getLowerExecutives.size()>0){
                   <ol>
                       @for(executive2 <- executive.getLowerExecutives) {
                           <li>@executive2.getFull_name</li>
                       }
                   </ol>
               }

           </li><br><br>
        }
       </ol>
```

And how this will work in other table like I have ExecutiveRecord entity with one-to-many relation with executive.how can a user view his lower executive history?

And if there is any other way in which a user can view all the executive below it?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how I worked it out in my situation.

If my hierarchy is like is the below picture.

[image]

Then while creating `B` you dint know who will be its desendents because they are not created  so you cant save them  but you have is one parent with the relation `OneToMany`  mean Executive have One parent and Many childs with this case you would be stuck to use recursive queries with multiple joins etc when finding childs(search executive with that parent id then searching that executive as parent id for other user and so on) which would be too heavy or complex.

So instead of doing `OneToMany` relation create a `ManyToMany` relation with itself means Executive can have many parent and many childs.

**Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Executive {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Executive> parentList = new ArrayList<Executive>();

    private String full_name;

}
```

creating a unidirectional relation of `ManyToMany`.When creating `A` map `A` as its own parent and when `A`(parent) is creating `B`(child) take all the parent of `A`(saved when creating A) and map as `B` 's parent and so on for other.

**Controller**

```
@Transactional
public static Result save() {
    Form < Executive > executiveCreateForm = executiveForm.bindFromRequest();

    Executive formExecutive = executiveCreateForm.get();

    Executive loginExecutive = Executive.findById(Long.valueOf(sesion.get("currentLoginUserId")));      //parent executive who is creating his child executive

    List < Executive > loginExecutiveParentList = new ArrayList < Executive > ();
    loginExecutiveParentList.addAll(loginExecutive.getParentList());
    formExecutive.setParentList(loginExecutiveParentList);

    JPA.em().persist(formExecutive);

    formExecutive.getParentList().add(formExecutive);
    JPA.em().merge(formExecutive);
}
```

View of executive table

[image]

and the mapping table looks like

[image]

So at each stages of creating a executive take its parent's `parentList` and map it to the  current executive parents and map himself to its parent.It made the query simple.

My JPQL looks like.

```
select e from Executive e left join e.parentList p where p.id=:id
```

where `:id` replaced by the id of the use you want all the desendent.

and If you need find user at particular level you can use [depth concept](http://technobytz.com/closure_table_store_hierarchical_data.html) with [ManyToMany with additional column approach](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the whole hierarchy you can simply go recursively through it until there is no children left to be fetched.

1. Make sure you always initialize your collections:

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="upperExecutive")
   private Collection<Executive> lowerExecutives = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
2. After you fetched the root Executive, you can go recursivily through the whole hierarchy:

   ```
   public void fetchChildren(Executive executive) {
       if(!executive.lowerExecutives.isEmpty()) {
           for(Executive lowerExecutive : executive.lowerExecutives) {
               fetchChildren(lowerExecutive);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

This way the hierarchy will be initialized when you have to display it in your UI, where you'd have to use the same recursion algorithm for displaying all children.

Comment: sorry for replying late it worked finding the subchilds.I want to ask that if this self refrencing+recursion is a good practice of handling large database?

Comment: For large data sets you need to limit the query results anyway and use some sort of pagination.

Comment: sorry if this is stupid question but I am using recursion here which will give me all user what I am doing now is adding all the recursive user to a list and passing it to view so how can I limit this list fetch because I cant stop the recursion in between .Suppose I want 5 user sorted by time field in mydb how can I do it because I am not writing any query?

Comment: In that case this will not work. If you want to pass filtering criteria you have to switch to using queries and the recursion will go in the DAO method as opposed to being in the entity.

Comment: is there any other approach which I can use in this condition of dynamic hierarchy so that I can fertch all the child of executive by `executive.getLowerExecutive()` using it once

Comment: Some databases (e.g PostgreSQL) support [tree structure and recursive queries](https://truongtx.me/2014/02/28/tree-structure-query-with-postgresql/).

Comment: thanks for all your response @Vlad .I have posted an answer below it would be a great help if you can check if the approach I posted is good or not.